# Clipping polygons using other polygons. (sf objects in R)

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, r-sf

I have fire polygon and ecoregion data. I am attempting to remove all fire polygons that do **not** fall into the specified ecoregion. I had tried using st_crop and st_intersection, but it keeps returning the same error.

```
#Subsetting fire polygons according to size

Dplus_size<-ten_yr_fire[ten_yr_fire$GIS_ACRES>=100,]

#Selecting for desired ecoregion (Sierra Nevada)

ecoregion<-st_read("ca_eco_l3.shp")
ecoregion_nad83<-st_transform(ecoregion, st_crs(Dplus_size))

snevada<-ecoregion_nad83[ecoregion_nad83$US_L3NAME == "Sierra Nevada",]

#Here is where I am running into issues: 
snv_fire<-st_crop(Dplus_size , snevada)

Error in scan(text = lst[[length(lst)]], quiet = TRUE) : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got 'ParseException:'
Error in (function (msg)  : ParseException: Unknown WKB type 12
```

Both objects are classes 'sf' and 'data.frame'.
I have not been able to get past the above errors.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem come from the CRS and/or the geom column you are using in `Dplus_size`.

This small reproducible example produce what you want:

```r
library(sf)

# one big polygon
pol1 = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0),c(8,0),c(8,8),c(0,8),c(0,0))))

# your two cases: inside and outside 
pol_in = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(4,4),c(4,6),c(6,6),c(6,4),c(4,4))))
pol_out = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(10,2),c(10,3),c(11,3),c(11,2),c(10,2))))

fire <- st_sf(data.frame(name = c("pol_in", "pol_out")),  
              geometry = st_sfc(pol_in, pol_out))

# quick plot
plot(pol1, xlim = c(0,12))
plot(fire$geometry, add = T)

# what you want
fire[pol1, ]
```

if it is not working the problem should be in the data.